# If I install an older, deprecated Java runtime, will that mess up applications that use the current Java version?

Tags: macos, java, adobe-photoshop

I own a really old version of Photoshop. After I upgraded to El Capitan when I attempt to launch Photoshop I get a dialog saying...

> To open "Adobe Photoshop CS5.1.app" you need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.

This is my current system Java version that came with the OS -->

```
java -showversion
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

I downloaded the old, deprecated Java 6 DMG, but I haven't installed it yet.

My question is, will it **replace** the Apple's distributed Java?

And if so, is that likely to break applications that are expecting an up-to-date Java version?

Or will it just make the older JRE available as an alternative for applications that need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you've downloaded the Java 6 installer [from Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_AU) it will work without affecting your current Java installation.

Answer (score 1):

For this question: "...is that likely to break applications that are expecting an up-to-date Java version?"

It's possible that some of your applications will not work.  If the developer is using a feature in a specific version of Java and you go to a lower numbered version, that feature might now work.  I want to emphasize *'might'*.  Nobody knows for sure if what you have on your machine will be impacted.  Of course, and this is most important, **you'll lose any security updates issued with the newer versions**.

Here's what Oracle has to say about downgrading:

> Most applications written for earlier versions of Java will run
>   without problems in newer versions of Java. However, there are some
>   cases where choices made by the developer to tie an application to a
>   specific Java version, or inability to update, can cause some
>   applications not to work with the latest Java versions.